# Regex for letter v preceded by underscore...and followed by any length number

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like below

```
string a= "idh_abcdef_normal_verymuch_ext_v1_20131101000000";
```

How do I find the index of "_v1" (small letter v followed by a number (**of any length**).

Below code is not working :(

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(a,"^[v][0-9]$").Index);
```

could someone help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that the string contains the given substring:

```
int index = Regex.Match(s, "_v\\d").Index;
```

otherwise

```
Match match = Regex.Match(s, "_v\\d");
if (match.Success)
    index = match.Index;
```

Comment: Will single "d" take care of more than one digit it might have ?

Comment: No. But it does not seem to be needed, since we are interested in the index of `_` only.

Comment: It can be this way also - "idh_abcdef_normal_verymuch_ext_v1" .Just wanted to make sure that there is no alphabets after v[number].

Comment: @Relativity Do you mean that e.g. in `.._v1A` does not contain the substring because the number is followed by `A`? My code finds index of `_v<digit>` in `<whatever>_v<digit><whatever>`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your regex:

```
^[v][0-9]$
```

Is that you are using a pattern to start with `v` and finish with a number. So, only strings like `v0`, `v2` ... `v9` are valid. Btw, you don't need to use `[v]` since it's exactly the same as `v`.

You can use a regex look ahead like this:

```
_v(?=\d)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/fG4cR6/1)**

Or a simple regex

```
_v\d
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/fG4cR6/2)**

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
_v\d+
```

As the regex you need.

Comment: if we didnt use "+" at the end, will it only take single digit ?

Comment: As you are interested in index like others answered you really don't need '+'. Because in string: `some_words_v123124` the index of `_v1` is the same as `_v123124`

Answer (score -1):

Why not a simple search:

```
string searchString = "_v1_";
int index = a.IndexOf(searchString);
string sNumber = a.Substring(index + searchString.Length);
long lNumber = long.Parse(sNumber);
```